# Spring Boot JmsConfig for Azure Service Bus

Tags: java, spring-boot, azureservicebus, jms-topic, jmstemplate

I am developing a Spring Boot producer that sends data to Azure Service Bus. The project is currently running on version 2.2.11.RELEASE. However, I encountered a roadblock when I realized that there is no Azure Service Bus library support for this version. Azure Service Bus support begins from version 2.5.0 and above. Since upgrading to a newer Spring Boot version poses significant challenges, I decided to implement the producer using JMS to send data to Azure Service Bus.

I have successfully implemented a similar exercise in our new project using ServiceBusSenderClient, which works flawlessly with the latest Spring Boot versions. Unfortunately, achieving the same functionality with Spring Boot 2.2.11-RELEASE has proven to be a challenge. This is why I turned to JMS as an alternative.

Below is what I have done and tried so far

application.yml

```
spring
  jms:
    servicebus:
      connection-string: ${AZURE_ENDPOINT}
      topic: ${TOPIC}
      topic-client-id: ${TOPIC_CLIENT_ID}
      pricing-tier: standard
```

below are new dependencies I added in my build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms:5.5.0'
implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-servicebus-jms:2.0.6'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq'
```

Part of code implementation

```
    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate ***jmsTemplate***;
        List<TradeEntity> tradeEntityList = eventsToBeSent.stream().map(DisruptionEventEntity::getTrade).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> dateList = eventsToBeSent.stream().map(
                DisruptionEventEntity::getMeasureDate).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

            for (String date1: dateList){
                SendMeasureRequestPayload sendMeasureRequestPayload =
                        new SendMeasureRequestPayload(sendMeasureValues,date1,"Daily")
                        
                    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(eventEntities)){
                        if (tradeEntity.getSfmConfiguration() !=null){
                            List<SendMeasureValues> measureValues = getMeasureValues(sfmConfiguration, sfmMeasureDTO);
                            sendMeasureValues.addAll(measureValues);
                            sendMeasureRequestPayload.setValues(sendMeasureValues);
                        }
                    }
                }

                log.info("Sending Data ...... {}", topic);
                jmsTemplate.send(topic,session -> session.createTextMessage(sendMeasureRequestPayload.toString())); // code to send data
                
            }
```

My Struggle is on the JmsConfig class and I would love any assistance that one could assist with

Below is the piece of code I tried but since I am using azure service bus it's not working because it's expecting an endpoint with tcp at the beging

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class **JmsConfig** {

    @Value("${spring.jms.service.connection-string}")
    private String connectionString;
    @Value("${app.azure.service-bus.topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter(){
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqConnectionFactory(){
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(connectionString);
    }

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(amqConnectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(topic);
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
}
```

Your guidance would be very appreciated thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot always using same SPRING-DATASOURCE-USERNAME & SPRING-DATASOURCE-PASSWORD from Azure Key Vault for two separate application

Azure Service Bus uses its own proprietary protocol for communication, so you can’t use the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` for this purpose. Instead, use the Azure Service Bus JMS library for configuration. configure JMS to work with Azure Service Bus in the Spring Boot 2.2.11-RELEASE application.

- Remove the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq` dependency from your `build.gradle` as you won’t be using ActiveMQ for Azure Service Bus.
- Update the `JmsConfig` class to configure JMS for Azure Service Bus. Use the `ServiceBusJMSConnectionFactory` provided by the Azure Service Bus JMS library.

```java
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.jms.ServiceBusJMSConnectionFactory;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.jms.ServiceBusJMSClientConfig;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter;

@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {

    @Value("${spring.jms.servicebus.connection-string}")
    private String connectionString;
    @Value("${app.azure.service-bus.topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Bean
    public ServiceBusJMSConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        ServiceBusJMSClientConfig config = new ServiceBusJMSClientConfig();
        config.setConnectionString(connectionString);
        return new ServiceBusJMSConnectionFactory(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(jmsConnectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(topic);
        jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
}
```

- Now, I am able to send messages to an Azure Service Bus topic using JMS.

[image]