Can we able to send acknowledgement programmatically when subscription is in receive and delete mode - JMS 1.0
I am trying to send acknowledgement programmatically(Java 17) using JMS version v1.0 in azure service bus with spring boot 2.5.0 with topic subscription is in RECEIVE AND DELETE mode.
I get the below error for the above scenario.
"Failed to connect after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry."
The code I tried is below.
ConnectionFactory factory   = new ServiceBusJmsConnectionFactory(<CONNECTION_STRING>, new ServiceBusJmsConnectionFactory());
Connection connection       = factory.createConnection();
connection.setClientId(<CLIENT_ID>);
connection.setExceptionListener(new MyExceptionHandler());
connection.start();
Session session = connection.createSession(true, session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Please Help.

Can you share more details of the code?

@DasariKamali I have got the below link as useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77039251/spring-boot-jmsconfig-for-azure-service-bus. Even though we have added dependencies related to azure service bus gets one error for the below import.  import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.jms.ServiceBusJMSClientConfig (Cannot resolve symbol 'ServiceBusJMSClientConfig')

Add this azure-servicebus-jms dependency to fix the above issue?

I tried the below Spring Boot application to send an acknowledgment to an Azure Service Bus topic subscription configured in RECEIVE_AND_DELETE mode with JMS.
Code :
ServiceBusService.java :
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.jms.ServiceBusJmsConnectionFactory;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.jms.ServiceBusJmsConnectionFactorySettings;
import javax.jms.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ServiceBusService implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceBusService.class);
    @Value("${azure.servicebus.connection-string}")
    private String connectionString;
    @Value("${azure.servicebus.topic-name}")
    private String topicName;
    @Value("${azure.servicebus.subscription-name}")
    private String subscriptionName;

    private Connection connection;
    private Session session;
    private MessageConsumer consumer;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        initializeConnection();
        sendMessage("Hello, Kamali!");
        receiveMessages();
        closeResources();
    }

    private void initializeConnection() throws JMSException {
        ServiceBusJmsConnectionFactory factory = new ServiceBusJmsConnectionFactory(connectionString, new ServiceBusJmsConnectionFactorySettings());
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.setClientID("<clientID>");
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        connection.start();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String messageContent) {
        try {
            Destination destination = session.createTopic(topicName);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(messageContent);
            producer.send(message);
            logger.info("Sent a single message to the topic: {}", topicName);
            producer.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            logger.error("Error sending message: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void receiveMessages() {
        try {
            Destination destination = session.createTopic(topicName);
            consumer = session.createDurableSubscriber((Topic) destination, subscriptionName);
            consumer.setMessageListener(message -> {
                try {
                    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                        String messageBody = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
                        logger.info("Received: {}", messageBody);
                        message.acknowledge();
                    }
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    logger.error("Error processing message: {}", e.getMessage());
                }
            });
            logger.info("Waiting for messages... Press enter to stop.");
            System.in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error receiving messages: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private void closeResources() {
        try {
            if (consumer != null) consumer.close();
            if (session != null) session.close();
            if (connection != null) connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            logger.error("Error closing resources: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

application.properties :
azure.servicebus.connection-string=<connecString>
azure.servicebus.topic-name=<TopicName>
azure.servicebus.subscription-name=<SubName>
logging.level.org.apache.qpid.jms=DEBUG

pom.xml :
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-servicebus-jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Output :
The following Spring Boot application ran successfully and sent message acknowledgement to the Azure Service Bus Topic.

